# Size of uiState Class for Fragments / Activities

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-components

### Question

Do I understand correctly, that according to googles [guide on app architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer#additional-considerations) the `uiState` of a fragment/activity is commonly described by only ONE class (see picture below)?

For me as a beginner to programming it looks like the `NewsUiState` is a combination between the representation of the data (`NewItemUiState`) and the screen related things (e.g. `isSignedIn`).

But on complex UIs the `uiState` class must be easily 100's of properties long or what am I missing?

[image]

Comment: It's common to break it down into smaller objects.  you could have 

data class NewUiState(val stateObject1, val stateObject2)

where stateObject 1 and 2 are also data classes.  This can nest arbitrarily.

Comment: Okay. But that makes it more difficult to update the `MutableStafeFlow<UiState>` which I manipulate in the ViewModel right? Before I could do `_uiState.update { it.copy (namedParameter = newValue) }` with nested objects I would need to do something like  `_uiState.update { NewUiState(it.stateObject1, it.stateObject2.copy (namedParameter = newValue) }`?

Comment: Complex code is complex.  Frequently in life you just get to choose where your complexity is.

Comment: True, but as a beginner you sometimes wonder if it's the complexity - or you not nothing how things are properly done.

Answer (score 1):

You can create more than one State `data class`.

**Sample UseCase**

```
sealed class UiState {
    data class Success(val data: Data) : UiState()
    data class Error(val error: Throwable) : UiState()
    object Loading : UiState()
}
```

**How to Handle**

```
fun handleUiState(uiState: UiState) {
    when (uiState) {
        is UiState.Success -> displayData(uiState.data)
        is UiState.Error -> displayError(uiState.error)
        UiState.Loading -> displayLoadingIndicator()
    }
}
```

**Other Sample**

```
sealed class UiState {
    data class Success(val data: Data) : UiState()
    data class Error(val error: Throwable) : UiState()
    object Loading : UiState()
    data class Validation(val errors: Map<String, String>) : UiState()
    data class Completed(val message: String) : UiState()
    object Init : UiState()
    object Empty : UiState()
}
```

The important thing here is to be able to break down the states related to the relevant screen. You can write your own uiStates for each component on the screen. This is **good** practice.
It can be combined with `Sealed class`. You can stream data with a single `stateflow` or `sharedflow`.

Comment: This helps with managing the higher level of the uiState I guess. Nevertheless, once I'm in the `Success(val data: Data` branch I need to pass all uiState related things to `data`, right? So I would still end up with a big uiState `Data` class....?!

Comment: You can make it generic. For example, type T.